# regex pattern for positive numbers without decimal points upto certain length

Tags: angularjs, regex, validation

we want our application to accept rollnumbers, we are using angularjs, we are unable to find a perfect way to validate a positive number which has to be greater than 0 and less than certain number like `10000000` but the problem is, our angularjs validation code is accepting numbers like `1.0` which is not acceptable for our application, please a correct way to doing it

```
<input
    type="number"
    name="student_rollnumber"
    class="form-control"
    ng-model="student.student_rollnumber"
    min="1"
    max="1000000000"
    required
    placeholder="Student Rollnumber (required)"
    step="1"
/>
```

Comment: Use `parseInt` to remove decimal part and use `<`, `>` for range validation.

Comment: @Tushar code? new to angular :)

Comment: The example in the docs shows how to do exactly this. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation

Comment: @MatthewGreen that is way to awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

with the help of @MatthewGreen found answer on official documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation

just in case they change it in future, i'm copying the current working version :)

```
<form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>
  <div>
    Size (integer 0 - 10):
    <input type="number" ng-model="size" name="size"
           min="0" max="10" integer />{{size}}<br />
    <span ng-show="form.size.$error.integer">The value is not a valid integer!</span>
    <span ng-show="form.size.$error.min || form.size.$error.max">
      The value must be in range 0 to 10!</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    Username:
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" name="name" username />{{name}}<br />
    <span ng-show="form.name.$pending.username">Checking if this name is available...</span>
    <span ng-show="form.name.$error.username">This username is already taken!</span>
  </div>

</form>
```

`script.js`

```
var app = angular.module('form-example1', []);

var INTEGER_REGEXP = /^\-?\d+$/;
app.directive('integer', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.integer = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
          // consider empty models to be valid
          return true;
        }

        if (INTEGER_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
          // it is valid
          return true;
        }

        // it is invalid
        return false;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes a difference performance wise, but I would use `return (viewValue % 1 === 0);` in place of the regex check they have. If nothing else that way you don't have to mess with needing to know regex. https://plnkr.co/edit/LxuE4sXOBrWYH9kei8jm?p=preview